# alinhar Linearlayout

Tags: android

Tenho tres LinearLayout dentro de um LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/l1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/l2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/l3"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

E estou colocando um `ImageButton` dentro de cada um dos layout assim

```
if(l==1){
                layout1.addView(btCategoria);
                layout1.addView(txtCategoria);
                Log.e("l1","entrou "+txtCategoria.getText());
                l=2;
            }else if(l==2){
                layout2.addView(btCategoria);
                layout2.addView(txtCategoria);
                Log.e("l2","entrou "+txtCategoria.getText());
                l=3;
            }else if(l==3){
                layout3.addView(btCategoria);
                layout3.addView(txtCategoria);
                Log.e("l3","entrou "+txtCategoria.getText());
                l=1;
            }
```

`btCategoria`e o `ImageButton` e o `txtCategoria` e um `TextView`

mais o primeiro não está ficando na mesma reta do resto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

queria saber porque a primeira imagem fica acima das outras ao lado

com este gridview vai funcionar mais ele tem isto `android:columnWidth="200dp"`, queria saber se tem como não definir ele porque se colocar um tamanho especifico vai ficar ruim dependendo do celular né .

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_widget"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/abc_search_url_text_holo"
    android:columnWidth="200dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidth" />
```

Comment: Já tentou usar `android:gravity="top"` no layout que contém os 3?

Comment: Ilgner, será que um GridView não atende melhor o seu layout do que montar essa Grid na mão?

Comment: e que o grid não funciona para todo tipo de celular

Comment: Recomendo muito você utilizar um `GridView` e deixar que o sistema controle a melhor maneira de apresentar as imagens/informações. E, além disso, você terá mais controle do layout de cada item do seu grid. O `GridView` está disponível desde a API 1 http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html e tem vários exemplos de como implementa-lo!

Comment: vou da uma olhada , e que o grid que eu tentei não funcionou

Comment: fiz um alteração na pergunta , porque tem um item la que vai da problema dependendo do celular , pode ficar grande demais ou ate pequeno demais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode definir o tamanho de cada item do seu `GridView` calculando pelo tamanho do device (dentro do seu adapter):

```
int size;

//Recuperando a quantidade de colunas que você declarou para seu GridView
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    size = getColumnSize();
} else {
    try {
        Field field = seuGridView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mColumnWidth");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        size = field.getInt(seuGridView);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        size = 0;
    }
}

// Fazendo o calculo para definir o melhor tamanho para cada item do seu GridView.
if (size <= 0) {
    float density = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    size = Math.round((float) 200 * density);
}

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//definindo a largura máxima para sua imagem (ou em todo o seu layout)
suaImagem.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Não esqueça de adicionar o atributo `scaleType` e `adjusteViewBounds` em sua `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgPhotoGalleryItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```